# Intend to come by

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases, phrase-choice

I came across a sentence which read as follows:

> The money you intend to come by through this expedition is not worth
> your life.

From the context, I interpreted "intend to come by" as the intention of earning or gaining.
When I searched online for this usage I find examples like, "Let me know if you intend to come by today" Here, it appears to mean "if you have an intention to drop by/come visit today."

Can someone explain how to understand the phrase "intend to come by" and when and how to use it?

Comment: I think it's more common in American English where they use "by" in the "into/to/at" sense. To me it also carries a "passing" notion: come by = pay a short visit, stop by (when you go somewhere else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two distinct meanings of "come by".

One meaning is *to make a visit*. It is *intransitive*, which means it doesn't take a direct object. This is the meaning in, "*Let me know if you intend to come by today.*" It means, *let me know if you intend **to visit** today*.

The other meaning is *to acquire or gain possession*. With this meaning, it is *transitive*, which means it takes a direct object. In this case, the object is "the money". So "*the money you intend to come by through this expedition*" means "*the money that you intend **to gain** through this expedition*".

Answer (score -1):

The phrase "come by" is used the same way as "come to". When used literally, as you ask or anticipate someone to come by your home or business, or you intend to go to their home or business, it's used to mean just that: they will go to you, or you will go to them. Most often, it refers to the place that's being gone to, rather than any person that's there, even though the person or people are who you're likely going to see.

> Come by the house and see your mother.

In the case of the phrase "come by some money" it's used in the same way as "come into some money"; the money is being received or acquired. It's most commonly used this way in less formal speech or writing. Interestingly, it might also be considered as more more polite or at least less direct; less harsh or brash.

Comment: The [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20by)  doesn't call it 'colloquial'.

Comment: "***Come into close contact with** the house and see your mother*" is not what that sentence means. Can you give a source that gives that definition?